# To get all checked items from a while loop (HTML & PHP)

Tags: php, html, loops, checkbox, while-loop

I am hoping that you guys could give me some tips or help on how I should allow the codes to work.

Firstly, I am trying to get a list of names of those who have signed up for an event, and having to check/tick the checkbox to confirm that they are in. However, as there are many events, the number of people who have signed up for each event may be different, and thus I called and made it into a while loop, as seen below.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $firstName = $row['first_name'];
    $lastName = $row['last_name'];
    ?>

    <form id="shortlistPeople" action = "doShortlistPeople.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" method = "post">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="shortlist" name="shortlistPeople[]" id="shortlistPeople" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

    <label for="shortlistPeople"><?php echo $firstName; ?> <?php echo $lastName; ?></label>                        
    </fieldset>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" class="btnSelect" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" name="shortlistPeople" value="Submit Shortlisted Persons"/>
    </form>

<?php
}
// end for loop

else {
    echo "No candidates to be selected";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Thus, in the doShortlistPeople.php:

```
<?php
$theShortlist = "";
if (!empty($_POST['shortlistPeople'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['shortlistPeople'] as $candidate_id) {
        $theShortlist .= $candidate_id . " ";

        $query = "UPDATE application SET shortlist='true'
        WHERE job_id = $id AND candidate_id = $candidate_id";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Error querying database');
    }
}
?>
```

Therefore, I really need your help.

/ = Checked/Ticked

EXAMPLE 1: (If there is only 1 candidate)

[/] Bob Lee

OUTPUT:

Selected:

Bob Lee

EXAMPLE 2: (If there is more than 1 candidate)

[/] Bob Lee

[/] Nicholas M.

OUTPUT:

Selected:

Bob Lee

Nicholas M.

EXAMPLE 3: (If there is more than 1 candidate)

[] Bob Lee

[/] Nicholas M.

OUTPUT:

Selected shown:

Nicholas M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this -

```
<form id="shortlistPeople" action="doShortlistPeople.php" method="post">
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $firstName = $row['first_name'];
        $lastName = $row['last_name'];
        ?>

        <label >
            <input type="checkbox" class="shortlist" name="shortlistPeople[]" id="shortlistPeople" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
            <?php echo $firstName; ?>
            <?php echo $lastName; ?>
        </label>

    <?php } else {
        echo "No candidates to be selected";
    } ?>

    <input type="submit" class="btnSelect" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" name="shortlistPeople" value="Submit Shortlisted Persons"/>
</form>
```

Basically your loop should not create multiple forms, just create multiple input elements.

PS:

- Your initial code is too buggy, to point out a mistake.
- I haven't tested the above code, its just to push you in right direction.